# FFMPEG conversion

Tags: php, ffmpeg, mp4, ogg, webm

I was looking at FFMPEG, and also specifically [FFMPEG PHP](http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/doc/api/index.php), and found that FFMPEG PHP had all the features I needed for some other sections of my website, (such as images) however it lacked the ability to save movie files.

What would the shell command be to convert the file `start.ogg` that is of an undetermined format (using OGG as an example) to both the Webm format in the file `end.webm` as well as the MP4 format in the file `end.mp4`.  I would like the bit rate for both video and audio to remain the same.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ffmpeg(1)` manual includes the following:

```
* You can encode to several formats at the same time and
define a mapping from input stream to output streams:
  ffmpeg -i /tmp/a.wav -ab 64k /tmp/a.mp2 -ab 128k /tmp/b.mp2 -map 0:0 -map 0:0
```

If you've only got one input and two outputs, the following does the trick:

```sh
ffmpeg -i /tmp/start.off /tmp/end.webm /tmp/end.mp4
```

Tested with a DivX 5 video input to WebM and MP4 outputs. Neat, thanks for the research project. :)